# ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-routing

I am trying to use the Component router of Angular 2.I have bootstraped the angular 2 application with a pre-exisitng angular 1 application. Here is my code:

main.ts

```
import { upgradeAdapter } from './upgrade-adapter';
import { ResAppComponent } from './resApp.component';
import { appRouterProviders } from './app.routes';

angular.module('utdApp').directive('appComponent', upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Component(ResAppComponent));

upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.body,['utdApp'],ResAppComponent,[appRouterProviders]);
```

resApp.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DisclosureComponent } from './disclosure.component';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router'

@Component({
selector: 'app-component',
template: `
<h1>My angular app</h1>
<nav>
<my-app-new></my-app-new>
<a routerLink="/route1" routerLinkActive="active">Route</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</nav>
`,
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
providers:[DisclosureComponent]

}) 

export class ResAppComponent{}
```

app.routes.ts

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig }  from '@angular/router';
import { DisclosureComponent } from './disclosure.component';

const routes:RouterConfig = [

{
    path: 'route1',
    component: DisclosureComponent,
}
];


export const appRouterProviders = [
provideRouter(routes)
];
```

disclosure.component.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, provideRouter } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
selector:'my-app-new',
template:`<h1>{{title}}</h1>`,
directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],

providers:[provideRouter]

})

export class DisclosureComponent
{
title="Success"

}
```

My error is something like:
[image]

I cant seem to find what is wrong. There isnot much information available about the component router for angular2.

Answer (score 0):

The new router needs to be provided in `bootstrap(AppComponent, [appRouterProviders])` instead of the root component.

```
providers:[provideRouter]
```

should be removed from `@Component()` of `DisclosureElement`

Comment: As far as I remember there are open issues with the new router and the upgradeAdapter. Please check the issues in the Angular2 GitHub repo.

Comment: You were right. This is an ongoing issue. I'll follow it there. Thank you. I'll post a response once I get this working.